# C# - Process.Start() - "The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed"

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process, permissions

I have an application that, when run, does the following:

- Check current user is MicaUser
- Start Application under MicaUser using Process.Start()
- Exit

This works fine on my Vista Dev machine, but when i try to run it under a restricted account in XP, i get the following error:
"The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed" 
In Process.Start()

The MicaUser account is set up on the local machine with permissions only to the areas that the application will need to modify. The User account i am testing on is a restricted user on the local machine. My development account is running in Vista on the Domain.

It seems this is a problem with accounts running on domain, but all the test accounts are local machine only.

Any thoughts as to what is causing this problem?

Regards

Tris

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be where i was assigning the domain for the ProcessStartInfo to ".".

I have set it to an empty string and the problems have gone away.